# How can I use Sass variables in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have a variable in Sass which determines how many `columns` are supposed to fit in 1 `row` for my grid system.

Normally, those are 12 `columns`.

In JavaScript I've got a function which checks if there are more then 12 `column`s in a `row`.

If so, it hides the whole row.

This function looks like this:

```
function checkColumns() {
    var maxColumns = 12;
    $('.row').each(function () {
        var elementsLength = $(this).children('.column').length;
        if (elementsLength > maxColumns) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any way to change the `maxColumns` variable to the same number which is in my sass variables? Besides then changing it manually every time I change the number in my sass file.

Comment: You can, in certain cases - but it's complicated. Read this, for starters: http://css-tricks.com/making-sass-talk-to-javascript-with-json/

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It would be more efficient to prevent more than 12 columns from existing in the first place.

Comment: @cimmanon That's commonplace for typographic grid systems :-) But I agree that I've never seen Javascript needing to care about the page's grid structure.

Comment: @Kos The OP is just discarding the information, though.  Why send the user the information if you're just going to delete it if it can't/won't fit.  It would be a different thing entirely if they were moving it (and even if they were, there are more efficient ways of going about doing so).

Comment: I was afk, one second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just seen this earlier this morning here: http://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json

First you need to include: https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars

**Install the gem:**

```
gem install sass-json-vars
```

**Place the variables in a json file**

```
// variables.json
{
    "font-sans": "Helvetica, sans-serif",
    "colors": {
        "red": "#c33"
    }
}
```

**Import the file in Sass to expose variable names:**

```
@import "variables.json"

body {
    color: map-get($colors, red);
    font: $font-sans;
}
```

**Require sass-json-vars when compiling**

```
sass style.scss -r sass-json-vars
```

Comment: thanks, but this does only work in the main file wich you are compiling right? Not in other imports?